# Can I push then display data from array in Angular

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, html

I want to add contact and contact details by sending them to MVC controller like an object and a list. Firstly i made an input boxes in HTML with scopes and an empty array in controller then I ng-repeat on it to display the inserted data. but unfortunately the console.log says undefined objects.

The controller

```
 .controller("forwardersCon", function ($scope, forwardersSrv) {

    $scope.contactsdetails = [];

    $scope.add = function ()
    {
        $scope.contactsdetails.push({ Contactname: $scope.contname, Contacttype: $scope.conttype, phones: $scope.contphn, fax: $scope.contfax })
        console.log($scope.contactsdetails);
    }

})
```

The HTML

```
<body ng-app="forwarders" ng-controller="forwardersCon">
<div class="form-horizontal">
    Company name<input type="text" id="contname" class="form-control" ng-model="contname" />
    Company type<select class="form-control" ng-model="conttype">
        <option>Shipping Line</option>
        <option>Logistics</option>
    </select>
    Company Phone<input type="text" id="contphn" class="form-control" ng-model="contphn"/>
    Company Email<input type="text" id="contfax" class="form-control" ng-model="contfax"/>
</div>
<br />
<table class="table table-responsive" id="salesdetails1">
    <tr>
        <th>Sales Name</th>
        <th>Sales Phone</th>
        <th>Sales Email</th>
        <th>Sales Fax</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="add" ng-click="add()">Add</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<h4>Contact Details</h4>

<table class="table table-responsive" id="salesdetails2">
    <tr ng-repeat="c in contactsdetails">
        <td>{{c.Contactname}}</td>
        <td>{{c.Contacttype}}</td>
        <td>{{c.phones}}</td>
        <td>{{c.fax}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>


<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/AnglForwarder.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
```

any help, how to push the inserted data from input box to array and then display it on html table. Thanks lot

Comment: Let me confirm do you want to send data contact and contact detail. is there one to many relation between them ?

Comment: yes there is a 1 to many relation

Comment: Your problem has been solve. I guessed

Comment: do you know a good video or material explain how to connect angularjs to MVC controller, Thanks

Comment: You just need to HTTP call to your controller. Simple, Have you ever used jquery ajax ?

Comment: i call http in my controller, but i want to make it all in Angularjs connected to MVC controller, without jquery

Comment: Go to youtube. search asp.net mvc with angular 1 crud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue occurs because you're "thinking" you adding sales data when you press the "Add" button but you are using the company details models when you populate the array.

Isn't this more logical, that you add the company details inputs next to the add button?

Working example here:

```js
angular
.module("forwarders", [])
.controller("forwardersCon", function ($scope) {

    $scope.contactsdetails = [];

    $scope.add = function ()
    {
        $scope.contactsdetails.push({ Contactname: $scope.contname, Contacttype: $scope.conttype, phones: $scope.contphn, fax: $scope.contfax })
        console.log($scope.contactsdetails);
    }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="forwarders" ng-controller="forwardersCon">

<table class="table table-responsive" id="salesdetails1">
    <tr>
        <th>Company Name</th>
        <th>Company Type</th>
        <th>Company Phone</th>
        <th>Company Email</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="contname" class="form-control" ng-model="contname" /></td>
        <td><select class="form-control" ng-model="conttype">
        <option>Shipping Line</option>
        <option>Logistics</option>
    </select></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="contphn" class="form-control" ng-model="contphn"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="contfax" class="form-control" ng-model="contfax"/></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="add" ng-click="add()">Add</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<h4>Contact Details</h4>

<table class="table table-responsive" id="salesdetails2">
    <tr ng-repeat="c in contactsdetails">
        <td>{{c.Contactname}}</td>
        <td>{{c.Contacttype}}</td>
        <td>{{c.phones}}</td>
        <td>{{c.fax}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: do you know a good video or material explain how to connect angularjs to MVC controller, Thanks

Comment: @Hassan Np! You should take a look at the $http service https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http. Then for the backend, what framework do you use? Core 2.1 or asp46?